# How to enable read permissions for organization sobject?

Tags: rest-api, profile, sobject, permission-sets

I'm trying to use the salesforce standard rest api to access the organization sobject so I can read the name of an organization I'm working with. I make a soql query `"SELECT Id,Name FROM Organization WHERE Id = '00DA0000000XXXXXXX'"` and it sends back `sObject type 'Organization' is not supported.`.

I've looked through Permission Set / Profile object permissions and the Organization object is not available. How do I give permissions for just this object type? I only need to be able to read the name and organization id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't explicitly give access to this object. The user you're running as should have View Setup and Configuration, and must not be a Customer Portal user. As far as I'm aware, as long as these two conditions are met, they should be able to at least query the object.